# unable to get response even by using Fake User Agent

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to scrape a website, but the output is `None`.
This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua=UserAgent()
header={'user-agent':ua.chrome}
responsejustdial=requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Builders-in-Faridabad/nct-10059255',headers=header)
print(responsejustdial)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you’re headers to the same as this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}

responsejustdial = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Builders-in-Faridabad/nct-10059255', headers=HEADERS)
>>> print(responsejustdial)
<Response [200]>
```