# BeautifulSoup - how can I find a span in a flex container?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried everything, but every time it returns `None`. I think that the `soup` doesn't even contain all of it. I've looked through the `soup` a bit and couldn't find it either, I tried it with some `<divs>` before that with the same result. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

"""<div class="galleryview__bottom-wrapper ">
<div class="galleryview__rating-wrapper">
<div class="galleryview__offercount">
<a href="pny-geforce-rtx-3090-oc-xlr8-gaming-epic-x-rgb-triple-fan-edition-vcg309024tfxppb-a2366527.html?hloc=de#offerlist" class="galleryview__offercount-link">
3 Angebote
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="galleryview__offer-wrapper ">
<div class="galleryview__offer">
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
<div class="galleryview__price">
<span class="galleryview__price-before">
ab
</span>
<a rel="noopener" href="pny-geforce-rtx-3090-oc-xlr8-gaming-epic-x-rgb-triple-fan-edition-vcg309024tfxppb-a2366527.html?hloc=de#offerlist" class="galleryview__price-link" onclick="
window._gh.track('Categorylist' , 'Click' , 'Price');
">
<span class="price">€ 2655,08</span>
</a>
<span class="galleryview__availability available" aria-label="
lagernd beim Händler
" data-tooltip-pos="up-right" tabindex="0"></span>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""
```

```
URL = "https://geizhals.de/?cat=gra16_512&xf=9816_03+05+16+-+RTX+3090"
r = requests.get(URL)
src = r.content
soup = bs(src, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'price'})
print(s)
```

Comment: When I visit the page I get banned with a  429 error code which means "Too Many Requests" [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHOP.png). Try adding a `user-agent` header. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757587/12349734)

Comment: Yep, that's the issue.  You got banned for scraping.  If you had taken the simplest debugging step of adding `print(soup.text)`, you would have seen that.

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see what you really have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be anything with a class of `price` in the HTML. There is though `gh_price`. Try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://geizhals.de/?cat=gra16_512&xf=9816_03+05+16+-+RTX+3090")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

div_main = soup.find('div', id='steel_list_container lazy-list--categorylist')

for div_row in div_main.find_all('div', class_='row'):
    name = div_row.find('div', class_='productlist__name').get_text(strip=True)
    print(name)
    price = div_row.find('span', class_='gh_price').get_text(strip=True)
    print(price, '\n')
```

Giving you output starting:

```
ASUS ROG Strix GeForce RTX 3090 OC, ROG-STRIX-RTX3090-O24G-GAMING, 24GB GDDR6X, 2x HDMI, 3x DP (90YV0F93-M0NM00)Anschlüsse: 2x HDMI 2.1, 3x DisplayPort 1.4a • Grafik: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 - 24GB GDDR6X - Desktop • Chip: GA102-300-A1 "Ampere", 82SM, 628mm² • Fertigung: 8nm (Samsung) • Chiptakt: 1395MHz, Boost: 1890MHz (OC Mode) • Speicher: 24GB GDDR6X, ...
ab€ 3099,00 

MSI GeForce RTX 3090 Gaming X Trio 24G, 24GB GDDR6X, HDMI, 3x DP (V388-011R)Anschlüsse: 1x HDMI 2.1, 3x DisplayPort 1.4a • Grafik: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 - 24GB GDDR6X - Desktop • Chip: GA102-300-A1 "Ampere", 82SM, 628mm² • Fertigung: 8nm (Samsung) • Chiptakt: 1395MHz, Boost: 1785MHz • Speicher: 24GB GDDR6X, 1219MHz, ...
ab€ 3074,99 

ASUS TUF Gaming GeForce RTX 3090 OC, TUF-RTX3090-O24G-GAMING, 24GB GDDR6X, 2x HDMI, 3x DP (90YV0FD1-M0NM00)Anschlüsse: 2x HDMI 2.1, 3x DisplayPort 1.4a • Grafik: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 - 24GB GDDR6X - Desktop • Chip: GA102-300-A1 "Ampere", 82SM, 628mm² • Fertigung: 8nm (Samsung) • Chiptakt: 1395MHz, Boost: 1770MHz (OC Mode) • Speicher: 24GB GDDR6X, ...
ab€ 3044,00
```